# Dealing with non-hardcoded domain names with mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, subdomain

I am migrating my application which provides a subsite for each user from domain.com/~user to user.domain.com. In order to do this, I wrote the following `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^~([a-z_]+)(/.*)?$ http://$1.%{HTTP_HOST}$2 [R=301,QSA,NC]
```

However, `%{HTTP_HOST}` doesn't do exactly what I need it to, because if for instance a user browses to `www.domain.com/~user`, it'll redirect to `user.www.domain.com` which is obviously not what I'm looking for.

I know that I can replace `%{HTTP_HOST}` with a hardcoded domain, but I don't want to do this either, because I will be rolling out the changes on multiple domains and don't want to have to customize it for each one. Is there a better way to make a singular change without hardcoding? (Furthermore, what if the base domain already has a subdomain -- ie. `sub.domain.com/~user` -> `user.sub.domain.com`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with this additional `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^~([a-z_]+)(/.*)?$ http://$1.%2$2 [R=301,QSA,NC]
```

This will remove the `www.` prefix from the host if present.